# Unknown symbol in an Excel spreadsheet cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I use an Excel spreadsheet that I inherited as part of my job, and it has a feature that I'm curious about.

One of the data cells has a small right angle shape in the bottom-right corner, and I don't know what the symbol is meant to denote.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Some cells from an Excel spreadsheet]

The symbol in question is in the rightmost column, second row from the bottom.

Comment: That looks like the mark of a "table" in Excel. If you click on that cell, does a "Table Tools" tab appear in Excel's ribbon? If so, it means that Excel is auto-formatting the area as a table.

Comment: Yes, clicking on that cell makes the Table Tools tab appear.  Thanks!

Comment: All right. Glad we solved that. I'll post it as an answer so you can mark the question closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the mark of a "table" in Excel. If you click on that cell, does a "Table Tools" tab appear in Excel's ribbon? If so, it means that Excel is auto-formatting the area as a table.

You can turn this off by clicking "Convert to Range" in the Table Tools > Design tab that appeared, but this will eliminate any pretty formatting that Excel has set up (eg, no more row banding on new rows).